# Workflow pre post images empty MSD CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I've a workflow which triggers on demand/automatic when opportunity status changes, recently I found this workflow not working properly. when I try to replicate the post/pre entity images are null in both the cases.

The workflow has an input parameter entity reference Account (customerid) it is also null.

On-pre setup.

MSD CRM 2013

Any suggestion.

Duplicate post [here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/397d61ba-0fb7-4e37-a13a-3a9ddac028ed/workflow-pre-post-images-empty?forum=crmdevelopment#397d61ba-0fb7-4e37-a13a-3a9ddac028ed)

Thanks,

Kiran.

Comment: and the code of your custom workflow activity? and a screenshot of this workflow?

Comment: If you are debugging the workflow to evaluate the data in the image, it will be null, and I still don't know why. But when I tried update the description field of the record to show the values in the image, it is valid and contains correct values.